# How can I remove the box in the smartdiagram?

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

I recently knew that there is a smartdiagram package. Thanks to samcarter who shows me his codes, my code is

```
\documentclass[t, 10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{lily}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\definecolor{ugreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
\definecolor{lgreen}{rgb}{0.9,0.95,0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Examples} % plain, allowframebreaks, shrink, squeeze
    \setbeamercolor{uppercol}{fg=white,bg=ugreen}%
    \setbeamercolor{lowercol}{fg=black,bg=lgreen}%
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol,shadow=true]{Example 2}
        \begin{minipage}[c][3cm]{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \smartdiagramset{
                border color=none,
                back arrow disabled=true,
                sequence item fill opacity=0,
                additions={
                    additional item offset=-7mm,
                    additional item fill opacity=0
                }
            }
            \smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{
                $X$,
                Noisy Channel,
                $f(\cdot)$,
                $Z$
            }
            {
                above right of module2/$Y$~~~
            }
        \end{minipage}
        If a function $f:Y \rightarrow Z$ is injective (one-to-one mapping) or invertible,
        then $Z=f(Y)$ is said to be a \textbf{sufficient statistic} relative to $X$.
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result screen is
[image: result_screen]

I hope to remove the box for X and Z, like
[image: desirable_result]

The first picture (upper one) is drawn by smartdiagram in TexMaker.

The second picture (lower one) is drawn by mspaint (windows program).

Please let me know how to change the picture above to below. There is no restriction on using smartdiagram. If there is another way to draw, it will be also welcomed. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Maybe add X and Z as additional modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you might take as a starting point. Obviously, this would need fine-tuning to adjust the spacing and fit your needs, but the basic idea should be reasonably clear, I hope.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs,quotes,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    block/.style={rounded corners, bottom color=#1, top color=white, drop shadow, text width=12.5mm},
    >=Stealth,
    draw=cyan!50!blue!50,
    line width=.75mm
  ]
  \graph [nodes={align=center, minimum height=12.5mm}, grow right=25mm, branch down=2.5mm]{
    "$X$" -> "Noisy\\Channel" [block=cyan] ->["$Y$"] "$f(-)$" [block=blue!50] -> "$Z$"
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chained nodes]

Comment: Nice answer. thank you very much. I changed my code to 99% of your code. Just changed from "grow right" to "grow right sep". Thank you very much.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Aha! Very good to know. (The graphs syntax still feels like an alien world to me!)